# Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wifi

I thought there was a way to test your applications in development over Wi-Fi. Is this possible?

I'd love to be able to untether my phone and develop wirelessly.

Comment: Not to mention, if you need to debug an app that communicates with a USB-attached device.

Comment: Now you can use this [Library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB) Install this plugin and enjoy debuging on wifi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: Starting from Android 11 [you could achieve this easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63988041/7356355) without using a USB cable at all.

Comment: I have created one small bash script to debug app over wifi: https://github.com/saifsms91/Shell-script-for-debugging-Android-Application-in-Wifi-mode

Comment: From Android 11 and above one can scan a QR code and connect the physical device without any USB cable.

Answer (score 2021, accepted):

See forum post *[Any way to view Android screen remotely without root? - Post #9](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=7594419&postcount=9)*.

1. Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working;
2. `adb tcpip 5555`. This makes the device to start listening for connections on port 5555;
3. Look up the device IP address with `adb shell netcfg` or `adb shell ifconfig` with 6.0 and higher or `adb shell ip -f inet addr show` with Android 10 and higher;
4. You can disconnect the USB now;
5. `adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555`. This connects to the server we set up on the device on step 2;
6. Now you have a device over the network with which you can debug as usual.

To switch the server back to the USB mode, run `adb usb`, which will put the server on your phone back to the USB mode. If you have more than one device, you can specify the device with the `-s` option: `adb -s <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555 usb`.

No root required!

To find the IP address of the device: run `adb shell` and then `netcfg`. You'll see it there.
To find the IP address while using OSX run the command `adb shell ip route`.

---

**WARNING**: leaving the option enabled is dangerous, anyone in your network can connect to your device in debug, even if you are in data network. Do it only when connected to a trusted Wi-Fi and remember to disconnect it when done!

---

@Sergei suggested that line 2 should be modified, commenting: "-d option needed to connect to the USB device when the other connection persists (for example, emulator connected or other Wi-Fi device)".

This information may prove valuable to future readers, but I rolled-back to the original version that had received 178 upvotes.

---

**On some device** you can do the same thing even **if you do not have an USB cable**:

1. Enable ADB over network in developer setting:
   [image: Screenshot Showing the option on]

   > It should show the IP address.
2. `adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555`
3. Disable the setting when done

---

Using Android Studio there is [a plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7856?pr=androidstudio) allowing you to connect USB Debugging without the need of using any ADB command from a terminal.

Comment: Typing 'adb tcpip 5555' is blocking the terminal. Is this to be expected? I waited about 5 minutes.

Comment: Why are you using `./adb shell` opposed to `adb shell`? The former doesn't execute of my machine.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Are you in Windows?

Comment: @metropolis Nope, I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: I had to do 'adb connect <device_ip_address>:5555' **after** disconnecting USB to make it work

Comment: Can i connect more than one device by that way?

Comment: This requires working adb over usb for the first step. Is there a non-root on-device way to switch adb to listen to tcpip, or is the setprop service.adb.tcp.port the only way to do it?

Comment: had the same issue, and because I'm noob I was trying ' adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xx ' and all I had to do was to remove the /xx part which I came to understand it refers to the port......just leaving this here

Comment: though its late, @srowley you might have to reconnect the usb cable , it worked for me and all these days i was blinded thinking root access was the only way! thanks  _/\\_

Comment: I had to disconnect the device from usb after 'adb connect <device_ip_address>:5555' for it to work.

Comment: To find the IP address of the device you can also do: **$ adb shell ip route**

Comment: Make sure both your machine and mobile device is on same Wifi network.

Comment: I've edited the reply adding a way to do it without the USB cable, a suggestion for an Android Studio Plugin and a Warning about security

Comment: i do not have the "ADB over network" option in debugging option.

Comment: I didn't had the option "ADB over network", nor usb cable, so i just downloaded the app on the play store named Wifi ADB and it works beautifully: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

Comment: adb over network option is not there still it works!!thanks!!

Comment: @ParthAnjaria **If you don't have the "ADB over network" option:** In that case you can do the same thing by following the steps provided in [Radu Simionescu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940301/3258851) or in answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604727/3258851)

Comment: Works fine, but terribly slow. No real practical reason to use this over a WiFi cable.

Comment: unable to connect to IP:5555: Connection refused. How to deal with the error?

Comment: another plugin that worked for me in ***Android Studio 2.2.2*** : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7856

Comment: Starting from Android 6.0, netcfg is not available and one needs to use ifconfig instead.

Comment: Device connected but not installing apk. Its showing Installing apk every time

Comment: no need to specify the port; something like `adb connect 192.168.123` should work just fine

Comment: you might get the error **"No route to host"** To fix that, before step 5 in the above answer, first, start your emulator then try the connecting device. Don't know what is happening but this trick works.

Comment: Does not work for USB C devices, with a USB C to USB C connection to Android Studio PC. You need a USB C (phone) to USB (pc) cable. Is there a way for USB C only connections?

Comment: `adb shell ifconfig` gives `Permission denied` error on my Pixel 3. I had to use `adb shell ip route` to get the local IP.

Comment: tip: write your own shell scipt so that you dont have to execute all those commands every start

Comment: doesn't work, device marked as offline : `adb devices` > 
`List of devices attached
192.168.0.140:5555      offline`

Comment: You can run adb pair ip:port on android 11 for pairing device

Comment: Hello, whats the device your talking about. Is it the phone or the pc?

Comment: my device don't have such field "ADB over network", but I installed plugin ADB Wi-FI then it works!

Comment: @Parth Anjaria, me too, but I installed ADB WiFi plugin and it works anyway!

Comment: If you are unable to use `adb shell ifconfig` or any other command to see ip address of mobile device. You can also check if from your router's setting/admin/firmware page which open by typing `192.168.1.1` in browser (for majority of routes).

Comment: A new update came, now you can actually scan a QR code and connect your physical device without any USB cable, and start debugging. (supported in Android 11 version and above only)

Answer (score 154):

*(No root required)* There is one best, easy and with UI method for Android Studio

IntelliJ and Android Studio plugin created to quickly connect your Android device over WiFi to install, run and debug your applications without a USB connected. Press one button and forget about your USB cable.

just install plugin **Android WiFi ADB**

Download and install Android WiFi ADB directly from

Intellij / Android Studio: **Preferences/Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories**

[image]

[image]

.

**Remember!** for first time to initialize the device you must have to connect using usb

Alternatively, you can download the plugin from the JetBrains plugin site and install it manually in: **Preferences/Settings->Plugins->Install plugin from disk.**

You can connect and manage your devices easily....... for more information read here  https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB

#### Update 2023

Tested with Android Studio 2022.3, and plugin no longer operates (even after below workaround).

But for most of older Android Studio versions,
it says "incompatible", while the plugin yet is operational!

That can be worked around, like:

- Open downloaded `.jar` and/or `.zip` file of the plugin.
- Find the `META-INF/plugin.xml` file.
- Edit said `.xml` file to replace `<depends>org.jetbrains.android</depends>` with `<depends>com.intellij.modules.androidstudio</depends>`
- Save and done! you can "Install from Disk" the result as you normally would.

Comment: it connect successfully, but when i unplugged usb cable.. wifi disconnect automatically

Comment: Use this a one off solution or does it stick?

Comment: I found another plugin more user friendly - its called `ADB WiFi Connect`

Comment: its not working on Huawei p8 lite how to fix. On Samsung its working well.

Comment: @SagarChavada It works from Marshmallow or up devices only

Comment: @SagarChavada I have faced the same problem and found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904545/adb-over-wifi-connection-lost-after-disconnecting-usb .

Comment: Plugin Error: Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Solution for "plugin error plugin android wifi adb is incompatible" stackoverflow.com/a/64464679

Comment: I really wanted this to work (because I had multiple `adb` installed), but my router is configured to give same phone always same LAN-IP anyway, hence I simply create a script which does `cd` to right `adb` folder (maybe one such script for each device IP?).

Answer (score 59):

If you want to enable wireless adb on the device without connecting with a USB cable **at all** (root required):

1. Install a terminal app on the device (like Android Terminal Emulator)
   Type the following
2. su
3. setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
4. stop adbd
5. start adbd

Since you already have the terminal opened, you can find the IP address of the device:

```
ip addr show
```

Then in your debugging environment run command:

```
adb connect ip.of.the.device
```

This will make the device to be listed as any other emulators you might have. Note that the TCP will stay opened until you reset the device.
You might also want to install a Wi-Fi Keep Alive app if you often experience disconnects.

Remember to close the TCP when connecting to public networks if you want to feel safe. You can do the following or simply restart the device:

1. su
2. setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
3. stop adbd
4. start adbd

Comment: Worked in my case, and didn't need USB connection.

Comment: Thank you it worked. For those who are unable to see the ip address of their android device, go to 
` Settings > Wireless > Wi-Fi `
and then long press the wifi which you are connected to. Then select `Modify network config` check on `Show Advance Options` and the scroll to `IP address

Comment: $ ./adb shell
shell@gtelwifiue:/ $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: @Bamaco - root required

Comment: "without connecting with a USB cable at all (root required)" a fancy joke. USB is not required but you have to root your device :)

Answer (score 59):

**Update :**

Starting from **Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Stable**, you can debug over Wifi just pairing the device by just scanning the QR code.

Quoting from the [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html) :

> **ADB over Wi-Fi**: Bumblebee includes a simplified flow to connect to
> your Android 11 and higher devices over Wi-Fi for deployment and
> debugging using ADB. After you enable debugging over Wi-Fi on your
> device, select the Pair using Wi-Fi action in the Physical tab of the
> new Device Manager to open the pairing wizard. Then follow the steps
> provided to pair to a device connected over the same network. Learn
> more.
>
> [image: Pairing Android Phone with Android Studio for Wifi debugging by scanning the QR code]

---

**Old post** :

With [new Android 11 you can debug your apps over WiFi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) without using an USB cable at all.

Quoting from [Android Studio User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+)

> **Connect to a device over Wi-Fi (Android 11+)**
>
> Android 11 and higher support deploying and debugging your app
> wirelessly from your workstation using Android Debug Bridge (adb). For
> example, you can deploy your debuggable app to multiple remote devices
> without physically connecting your device via USB. This eliminates the
> need to deal with common USB connection issues, such as driver
> installation.
>
> To use wireless debugging, you need to pair your device to your
> workstation using a pairing code. Your workstation and device must be
> connected to the same wireless network. To connect to your device,
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. On your workstation, update to the latest version of the SDK Platform-Tools.
> 2. On the device, enable developer options.
> 3. Enable the **Wireless debugging** option.
> 4. On the dialog that asks **Allow wireless debugging on this network?**, click **Allow**.
> 5. Select **Pair device with pairing code**. Take note of the pairing code, IP address, and port number displayed on the device (see image).
> 6. On your workstation, open a terminal and navigate to `android_sdk/platform-tools`.
> 7. Run `adb pair ipaddr:port`. Use the IP address and port number from step 5.
> 8. When prompted, enter the pairing code that you received in step 5. A message indicates that your device has been successfully paired.
>
> ```
>     none
>     Enter pairing code: 482924
>     Successfully paired to 192.168.1.130:37099 [guid=adb-235XY]
> ```
>
> 9. (For Linux or Microsoft Windows only) Run adb connect ipaddr:port. Use the IP address and port under Wireless debugging.

Comment: What about step 9 for Mac users?

Comment: @Aziz I do not think it is necessary for mac users, otherwise they have mentioned it.

Comment: To target the device run

`adb devices 
// grab the full deviceId example adb-AZ04AB-1234._adb-tls-connect._tcp.
adb -s adb-AZ04AB-1234._adb-tls-connect._tcp. shell ls // should work and list files on that device
`

Comment: On bumble bee worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: if only it was working this smooth...

Comment: Bumblebee pairing using QR code doesnt work with Pixel, there's just "error pairing the device"

Comment: CloudFare does not allow connecting

Answer (score 49):

I found my answer [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless):

1. Connect Android device and adb host computer to a common Wi-Fi network accessible to both. We have found that not all access points are suitable; you may need to use an access point whose firewall is configured properly to support adb.
2. Connect the device with USB cable to host.
3. Make sure adb is running in USB mode on host.

   ```
   $ adb usb
   restarting in USB mode
   ```
4. Connect to the device over USB.

   ```
   $ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   ######## device
   ```
5. Restart host adb in tcpip mode.

   ```
   $ adb tcpip 5555
   restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
   ```
6. Find out the IP address of the Android device: `Settings -> About tablet -> Status -> IP address`. Remember the IP address, of the form `#.#.#.#.`
   *sometimes its not possible to find the IP-address of the android device, as in my case. so u can get it using adb as the following:

   $ adb shell netcfg
   and the should be in the last line of the result.*
7. Connect adb host to device:

   ```
   $ adb connect #.#.#.#
   connected to #.#.#.#:5555
   ```
8. Remove USB cable from device, and confirm you can still access device:

   ```
   $ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   #.#.#.#:5555 device
   ```

You're now good to go!

If the adb connection is ever lost:

1. Make sure that your host is still connected to the same Wi-Fi network your Android device is.
2. Reconnect by executing the "adb connect" step again.
3. Or if that doesn't work, reset your adb host:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```

and then start over from the beginning.

Comment: worked perfectly but i had to remove my cable before connecting to the device ip for the device to show up after setting up the connection.

Comment: `adb kill-server` worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

The adb utility does have the ability to connect to a device over TCP/IP. However, adbd is not normally listening for TCP connections.

If you want to get it running, you need an engineering device (in other words, you need root). Then follow the directions in this post:

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Since this only works on eng devices, it's not officially supported. Use at your own risk, expect bugs, etc.

Comment: No cause for alarm, I'm running a Nexus One and I'm ready to get my hands dirty :)

Comment: i tried to connect more than one device(apparently two)...but could not make it happen..! Is there any way to connect more than one device to debug via wifi(without usb..)...

Comment: How about this official guide? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Answer (score 36):

[image][image]

In `Developer options` of Android 11, there is `Wireless debugging`. Make sure your laptop and phone under same network then execute 2 command below. Note that, the `port` for pair is different to the `port` for connect and you just need to pair on the first time (later you just need connect).

**adb pair ipaddr:port**

```
adb pair 192.168.1.6:42049

// will output
Enter pairing code: 696686
Successfully paired to 192.168.1.6:42049 ...
```

**adb connect ipaddr:port**

```
adb connect 192.168.1.6:37203

// will output
connected to 192.168.1.6:37203
```

**Addition**
These command will only work on android studio terminal, if you are in "platform-tools" directory. `cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>`

Comment: Coudn't connect using android studio, but using above commands connected successfully.

Comment: No need to open android studio to pair. Good if your coding using react-native.

Answer (score 29):

For all , this , there exists **a better method** (**EASIEST METHOD**) :

1 ) A plugin for Android studio exits , called **Android wifi ADB**

2) Go to file -> settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories

3) Look for  **Android WiFi ADB**  , click on **INSTALL** , and then **restart on prompt**

4) You will see a **new icon** , which is your new plugin .

Now **to make this work** :

5) Go to your phone's developer option and enable DEBUGGING (must)

6) Also enable , **ALLOW DEBUG OVER TCP/NETWORK**

7) Attach your phone via **USB** , and make sure , both phone and your pc/laptop are connected to the same network (either hotspot or wifi)

8) **CLICK ON THE NEW ICON** (ie your **ANDROID Wifi ABD**)

9) Your phone get's detected and get's **connected over wifi/hotspot** , and hence now you may **disconnect the usb** . This is a one time process , hence you may not need to keep phone connected over usb .

This will save your phone from irregular charges and also , a remedy for short length usb cables .

Comment: **WiFi ADB ULTIMATE** plugin also helps

Comment: it connect successfully, but when i unplugged usb cable.. wifi disconnect automatically

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work (any more) I see an incompatible dialog in Androiud Studio 4.1.1 "supported only in Intellij IDE"

Answer (score 21):

**Install plugin Android WiFi ADB**

*Download and install Android WiFi ADB directly from Android Studio*:

**File > Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories-> Android WiFi ADB ->Install ->Connect with cable for first time -> Click on "Connect" -> Now remove cable and start doing debug/run.**

***Check ss for your reference*** :

[image: Android WiFi ADB]

Comment: This is working for me in very easy manner. Thanks Tarit Ray for sharing.

Comment: Thanks, after doing step, and once it showed connected I removed the usb, and I was able to use debug over wifi

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks @NoumanCh, and Sanjeev I got this answer from Android official

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Android 11 click on the build version many times to activate the developer option then go to Settings>Advanced>Developer options. Scroll to debugging and turn on the "Wireless debugging" checkbox. Then open the menu debugging by touching the "Wireless debugging". Select "Pair device with paring code" and you will see the address for pairing with a pairing code. write this command in your desktop terminal to pair with your Android device.

```
adb pair 192.168.XXX.XXX:XXXX   <--------- the address showing on screen under paring code
```

Use the paring code to connect.
But wait we are not connected to adb yet.
After you have successfully paired your device once. You can connect your adb anytime you turn on your Wireless debug option. To connect your adb every time before you use it from now on you don't need the pairing address anymore instead you will use the given address that shows when you enter the Wireless debug menu.

```
adb connect 192.168.XXX.XXX:XXXX    <--- this address shows inside wireless debug menu
```

Comment: Worked like a charm mate :)

Comment: This worked for me on Android Flamingo, the second instruction is very important

Answer (score 12):

After a long search I found :

**I must run**

```
adb connect <device_ip_address>:5555
```

**after disconnecting USB**.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote [a shell script](https://gist.github.com/Folyd/6ee1f27fbacd698419d8) which can let you debug an Android device via Wi-Fi.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Notice: if unable to connect to [ip]:5555,
#try adb kill-server then try again.

adb shell ip route > addrs.txt
#Case 1:Nexus 7
#192.168.88.0/23 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.89.48

#Case 2: Smartsian T1,Huawei C8813
#default via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#8.8.8.8 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#114.114.114.114 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#192.168.88.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.89.152  metric 30
#192.168.88.1 dev eth0  scope link  metric 30

ip_addrs=$(awk {'if( NF >=9){print $9;}'} addrs.txt)

echo "the device ip address is $ip_addrs"

echo "connecting..."

rm addrs.txt

adb tcpip 5555

adb connect "$ip_addrs"
```

Comment: newer versions of tools requires the port to be given so change the last line to ```adb connect "$ip_addrs:5555"``` to make it work again. Thanks for the script anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Following steps are standard ones to follow( mostly same as previous answers):-

- adb tcpip 5555.
- adb connect your_device_ip_address.
- adb devices (to see if devices got connected).

**But in some cases above steps gives error like "unable to connect to device. Make sure that your computer and your device are connected to the same WiFi network." And you notice the devices are already on the same network.**

In this case, install this plugin "Wifi ADB Ultimate" and follow below steps.

1. Connect the device once through USB.
2. Refresh the list to check whether its connected.
3. Go to About Phone > Status > IP Address and note your IP address(e.g. 198.162.0.105).
4. Come back to Android Studio and fill in this IP as done in below photo and hit the run button.

---

[image]

---

Now, you are good to go!

Comment: I had several IP adresses, but I selected started from 192.168.0.*** and then it works!

Answer (score 8):

To complete the answer of @usethe4ce, if you have more than one device or emulators, the `adb tcpip 5555` will give `error: more than one device/emulator`.

In this case you need to give the serial number of the desired device:

1. `adb devices`

   > List of devices attached
   >
   > 33001229        device
   >
   > emulator-5554   device
2. `adb -s 33001229 tcpip 5555`
3. Find your device's IP in my case I can find it from the device's wifi connected settings.
4. `adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555`

Answer (score 7):

Though there are so many good answers, here is my two cents for the future me :P and for anyone who wants it quick and easy.

**For Mac:**

- connect the device using USB first and make sure debugging is working. Disconnect any other devices and quit emulators.
- open ***terminal*** and run the following script

  ```
  adb tcpip 5555
  adb connect $(adb shell ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d: -f2):5555
  ```
- disconnect USB connection and the device should be available for WiFi debugging

**Explanation:**

`adb tcpip 5555` commands the device to start listening for connections on port 5555

`adb connect $(_ip_address_fetched_):5555` tells to connect on port 5555 of the `_ip_address_fetched_` address

*where `_ip_address_fetched_` includes following:*

`adb shell ifconfig` getting internet configurations using adb shell

`grep "inter "` filter any line that starts with *inter*

`grep -v 127.0.0.1` exclude localhost.

At this point, output should be like:

> inet addr:**###.###.#.###**  Bcast:**###.###.#.###**  Mask:255.255.255.0

`awk '{print $2}'` get the second part of the components array, separated by space *(I'm using zsh)*.

The output up to this point is

> addr:**###.###.#.###**

`cut -d: -f2` split the string by delimiter **:** and take second part. It will only take your device IP address

Answer (score 6):

For Windows:

Step 1. Make a batch file with the below commands and call the file `w.bat`.

Step 2. Copy the below contents in `w.bat`, and save it in any of the folders which are in `%path%` of your Windows system

```
echo ***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***
echo ***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***

adb devices
echo ***Remove cable from the phone now***
adb tcpip 9000

adb connect 192.168.1.1:9000
adb connect 192.168.1.2:9000
adb connect 192.168.1.3:9000
adb connect 192.168.1.4:9000
adb connect 192.168.1.5:9000
adb connect 192.168.1.6:9000
```

//<-- Till here -->

Step 3. Connect your phone and PC with a cable

Step 4. Ensure the phone is in Wi-Fi mode

Step 5. Remove the cable when the batch file tells you to

Step 6. Type `w.bat` on the Windows prompt (start -> run -> type `CMD`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) (black screen is Windows DOS prompt), if you copied it in one of the path folders then you can run from anywhere, else run from the folder where you created this file.

The output of the batch file will be something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32>w

C:\Windows\System32>echo ***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***
***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***

C:\Windows\System32>echo ***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***
***Get phone in Wi-Fi mode***

C:\Windows\System32>adb devices
List of devices attached
d4e9f06 device

C:\Windows\System32>echo ***Remove cable from the Phone now***
***Remove cable from the Phone now***

C:\Windows\System32>adb tcpip 9000
restarting in TCP mode port: 9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.1:9000
unable to connect to 192.168.1.1:9000:9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.2:9000
connected to 192.168.1.2:9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.3:9000
unable to connect to 192.168.1.3:9000:9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.4:9000
unable to connect to 192.168.1.4:9000:9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.5:9000
unable to connect to 192.168.1.5:9000:9000

C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 192.168.1.6:9000
unable to connect to 192.168.1.6:9000:9000
```

Note 1: Find this in the output, (ignore all ->unable to connect<- errors)

```
connected to xxx.xxx.x.x:9000
```

If you see this in the result, just remove the cable from PC and go to Eclipse and run to install the app on the device; that should be it.

Note 2: DISCONNECT OR TO SWITCH WIRELESS MODE OFF: Type the below command. It should say restarting in USB mode - at this stage PC and computer should NOT be connected with a cable:

```
C:\Users\dell>adb usb
restarting in USB mode
```

Note 3: Steps to find the IP address of the phone (taken from Stack Overflow)

Find IP address of MY PHONE:

```
a. Dial *#*#4636#*#* to open the Testing menu.
b. In the Wi-Fi information menu: click Wi-Fi Status
c. Wi-Fi status can be blank for the first time
d. Click Refresh Status
e. In the IPaddr: <<IP ADDRESS OF THE PHONE IS LISTED>>
```

Note 4: My Phone Wi-Fi connection IP address range typically is as the mentioned IP addresses below,

192.168.1.1

192.168.1.2

192.168.1.3

192.168.1.4

192.168.1.5

192.168.1.6

Note 5: if you get any other sequence of IP addresses which keep getting reassigned to your phone, you can just change the IP address in the `w.bat` file.

Note 6: This is a *brute-force* method, which eliminates all manual labor to keep finding IP address and connecting to Eclipse / Wi-Fi.

SUCCESS Note 7: So in short, the regular activity would be something like this:

```
Step 1. Connect PC and Wi-Fi via a cable
Step 2. Start CMD - to go to Windows DOS prompt
Step 3. Type "w"
Step 4. Find connected command in the output
Step 5. Success, remove cable and start using Eclipse
```

Comment: If you use *@echo* instead of *echo* you get less noise when running your bat file.

Answer (score 6):

Best and super easy way to do this is:-

1. Make a batch file :-

> adb devices
>
> adb tcpip 5555
>
> adb connect 192.168.9.120:5555 ( Your phone ip xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5555 )

2. Place this file into your android sdk platform-tool folder.
   Example:- C:\Users\'user_name'\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
3. Right click file > sendto > Desktop(create shortcut )
4. That's it....

Now you just need to connect your phone through USB , then open desktop shortcut and disconnect your phone...

Comment: Does it require root?

Comment: @CoolMind No. Rooting not required

Comment: Agree. I have already done without root. In my case I couldn't get screenshots, also often logs were lost. So I refused Wi-Fi debugging.

Answer (score 5):

1. In Device Settigs-> "Developer options" -> "Revoke USB debugging authorizations".
2. Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working.
3. `adb tcpip 5555`
4. `adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555`
5. Disconnect USB
6. `adb devices`

Answer (score 5):

From search and from some answers i use this method and it work fine
and you must know that tcpip is not always 5555 , you must find it just follow this
you need first to download platform-tools

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

extract **platform-tools** folder to **C** drive and run **Powershell** there (Right click >> PowerShell >> Open here)

**#Connect phone with usb cable**

```
PS C:\platform-tools> adb kill-server
PS C:\platform-tools> adb shell ip route > addrs.txt
```

**#this give you your tcpip**

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 
* daemon started successfully
PS C:\platform-tools> adb tcpip 5037
restarting in TCP mode port: 5037
```

**#Disconnect phone
#adb connect <phone_ip>:5037**

```
PS C:\platform-tools> adb connect 192.168.43.1:5037
connected to 192.168.43.1:5037
```

Now you can see your phone in Android studio

Comment: I have an android 8 and I badly want to test my apps over WIFI instead of USB. Our answer solved my issue. It's so easy to debug app over WIFI. Thank You........

Comment: Still counts for tablet with Android 6.0

Answer (score 3):

The best way is using ADBConnect ([Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plugin) and ADB Wireless (app for Android device).

Answer (score 3):

```
>##    open command prompt with Run as Administrtor ##

    adb connect ipdevice:5037
```

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu / Linux:

1. Make sure your device is working for debugging: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling
2. Go to your sdk folder and find the folder platform-tools
3. Use `./adb devices` to list the connected devices. Make sure it is only one device connected and no emulator running.
4. Find your device IP address, you can find it in your device:
   http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless, or got adb shell like this: `./adb shell` then `netcfg`. You will see a list of IP addresses. Find `wlan0`, in my case 192.168.100.3/2.
5. `./adb tcpip 5555`
6. Finally enter `./adb connect <Your device IP Address>:5555` in your terminal. You can now deploy the application to your device over Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 3):

Note :- Android Phone must be rooted and no need of usb cable.

Install **wifi adb** in android phone from playstore

**link** :-https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb

**For Windows**

I am using this technique , which is very easy.

1) download adb :

link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcxw0yy3jvydupd/adb-setup-1.4.3.exe?dl=0

2) Run exe :- when you see blue screen press y enter .
[image]

3) Now open your wifi adb apk , just grant root permission and must be remember you android phone and system on the same network by wifi or hotspot .

4) Open Wifi adb apk , you will get some ip address like , `adb connect 192.168.2.134:5555` 
Note this ip may be very from system to system , now put this information to your command prompt and hit Enter .

5) Open cmd from anywhere enter `adb connect 192.168.2.134:5555` .

6) Finally you successfully connected to adb . it will show message like 
`connected to 192.168.2.140:5555`

**For Mac Os**

This is the easiest way and will provide automatic updates.

1)Install homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2)Install adb

```
brew cask install android-platform-tools
```

3)Start using adb

```
adb devices
```

4) Open Wifi adb apk , you will get some ip address like , `adb connect 192.168.2.134:5555` Note this ip may be very from system to system , now put this information to your terminal and hit Enter .

5) Open terminal in `mac os` from anywhere enter `adb connect 192.168.2.134:5555` .

6) Finally you successfully connected to adb . it will show message like  `connected to 192.168.2.140:5555`

I hope its help you ,Thank You !

Answer (score 3):

If you are a windows user and your android sdk is located at C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk then you can follow this method. If your andoid sdk not located there, replace that path to the below code.

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" disconnect
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" shell ip route > %temp%\addrs12321.txt
For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In ("%temp%\addrs12321.txt") Do Set "lastline=%%A"
FOR %%C IN (%lastline%) DO SET last=%%C
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" tcpip 5555
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" connect %last%:5555 > %temp%\adbresult.txt
set /p result=<%temp%\adbresult.txt
del /f %temp%\addrs12321.txt
echo MSGBOX "%result%" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
del %temp%\adbresult.txt /f /q
```

**Step 1.**

1. Turn on usb debugging,
2. Connect your phone to windows machine
3. select file transfer in usb options menu in android menu (if found)

**Step 2.**

1. copy above code
2. save as its extension like .bat, eg filename.bat
3. double click on the file you saved. done

> note you can connect any time by running that file while the device
>   being connected with the pc with usb debugging is turned on.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One imp point probably missed here - once you do a adb remount - the TCP connection is lost hence you have to do a adb connect *IP:port* once over again

Answer (score 2):

Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working. these steps are taken if you already have installed adb and set it's path in environment varialbe

1. open cmd and type the following
2. `adb tcpip 5555`
3. find the IP address with `adb shell ip route`
4. `adb connect DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS:5555`
5. Disconnect USB and proceed with wireless debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple script for Windows:

Step 1. Make a batch file with the below commands and call the file wifi_dedug.bat and copy the below contents:

```
    adb tcpip 5555
    pause
    adb shell "ip addr show wlan0  | grep 'inet ' | cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1" > tmpFile 
    pause
    set /p ip= < tmpFile 
    @echo %ip%
    del tmpFile
    @echo %ip%
    adb connect %ip%
    pause
```

Step 2. connect your device to pc.

Step 3. start batch file (key enter when requested)

Step 4. disconnect your device and deploy/debug via wifi.

Comment: It's not usefull if you don't explain whats happening

Answer (score 2):

1- For this I am considering you have already installed the latest version of Android studio. If not you can download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio).

2 - You can set the platform tools path in environment variable (optional).

3 - Make sure your device and pc connected to same network.

- plug in the data cable from pc to device.
- Now, type adb tcpip 5555
- remove data cable.
- Then type adb connect 192.168.43.95
- here 5555 is the port number and  192.168.43.95 is the ip address of the mobile device you can get id address from the mobile settings .
- Then go to About device and go to status you can see the ip address of the device.
- You can connect multiple device from different ports which can give ease in development.
- Or you can go to this link for brief description with screenshots. http://blogssolutions.co.in/connect-your-android-phone-wirelessly-by-adb

Answer (score 2):

### Edit August 2021

Google removed it with ArcticFox Beta 03 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190411383 but in Android Studio Bumblebee it's still there. It looks like they have to much issues with it, that's why it's just in canary builds

### Original post

This **Android WiFi ADB plugin** doesn't work in 4.1.1 (anymore)

[image]

But there is much more simple solution:
If you have an Android 11 (api30) device you should use Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Canary) to connect. **It's super easy**

[image]

Then you go to developer settings and scan QR code. That's it.
You can use connected device in other (older) Android Studio version now as well

Comment: I have the stable 2020.3.1 installed and unfortunately no menu option exists.

Comment: Actually, if I go to Help > Find Action, it finds it. But, if I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: @MattCosentino Google removed it with ArcticFox Beta 03 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190411383 but in Android Studio Bumblebee it's still there. It looks like they have to much issues with it, that's why it's just in canary builds. Btw, it's allowed to rate my post

Comment: Solution for "plugin error plugin android wifi adb is incompatible"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464679

Answer (score 1):

**Steps for Android Wifi debugging with ADB:**

```
$> adb devices   // check all usb debuggable devices connected.

$> adb -d shell  // Access device shell.

shell> ifconfig  // Check and copy wifi ip-address eg:192.168.1.90

shell> exit      // Exit from android device shell.

$> adb tcpip 5000   // open TCP port 5000 (or any available)

$> adb connect 192.168.1.90:5000  // connect to device via wifi ip over specific TCP port.

$> adb devices   // you will get debuggabled android device over wifi.
```

> **Required:** Connect your android device to computer via USB with
>   developer mode enabled. Also connect your android device and computer
>   to same wifi router (or use tethering).

Answer (score 1):

For Android 11 phones and Android Studio Bumblebee version, there's new update. You can just scan the QR code from your Android phone and
Boom! It is connected.

Saving time to copy paste the process.
Helpful official documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+)

Comment: Always include a short summary of the instructions on external links. That way the answer will be useful in the future when the link will (surely) be dead.

Comment: Simple and elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

just download the Google ADB:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
extract it and use it.
for example, pairing:

```
./adb pair 192.168.8.90:42119 274678
```

then connect:

```
./adb connect 192.168.8.90:38995
```

the use for example software like scrcpy:

```
export ADB="/home/luca/Downloads/platform-tools/adb"
scrcpy
```

Comment: Thank you Sweta for revision.
Anyway I meant scrcpy (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)

Answer (score 0):

Radu Simionescu's answer worked for me. Thank you. For those who are unable to see the ip address of their android device, go to 
`Settings > Wireless > Wi-Fi`
and then long press the wifi which you are connected to. Then select `Modify network config` check on `Show Advance Options` and the scroll to `IP address` section.

After installing `adb` in your system, do run
`killadd adb` and `adb start-server`
to refresh adb. Sometimes we could get issues like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955484/cannot-run-adb-command-in-ubuntu-adb-server-is-out-of-date)

Answer (score 0):

#### android Wireless Debugging (MAC)

step 1: go to sdk folder (common path "/Users/macname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools")
    open cmd here run "adb devices"
    output - List of devices attached

if adb command not found in cmd type 
./adb --help
OS X / macOS: typically ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile
Add the following line there and replace the path with the one where you installed platform-tools:

step 2:
$ export PATH="/Users/macname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

step 3:
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
ZH99FF7FTY      device

step 4:
$ adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

step 5:
$ adb connect 10.124.32.18:5555
connected to 10.124.32.18:5555

Next Time repeat step 4 and 5 to reconnect 
Or if Device reboot and not connect follow step again
BEST OF LUCK

Answer (score 0):

Download the app `Wifi ADB` on the play store. Very easy to use and works like a charm! :)

Comment: it's not useful when you need to root to use those app

Answer (score 0):

```
first you shold connect your device with usb to pc after that run cmd and drag and drop adb.exe that is in sdk/platform-tools path and write below code :

    ....\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices

    .....\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe tcpip 5555

    .....\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe connect Ip address:5555
```

Answer (score 0):

When you follow the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938/6117565, you might get the error **"No route to host"**.

#### To fix that, before step 5 in the above answer, first, start your emulator then try the connecting device. Don't know what is happening but this trick works.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your pc and android is on same wifi connection.
2. start adb server from your phone...
   download any wireless adb app from playstore...here is what I am using
   WiFi ADB - Debug Over Air
3. on your computer start cmd and run:
   Code (csharp):
   adb connect 192.168.1.100:5555
   Be sure to replace 192.168.1.100 with the IP address that is actually assigned to your device.

check if it is connected by :
Code (csharp):
adb devices
4. start unity or restart if it is already running and hit play..

5. tadaa...........:eek:

Answer (score 0):

I read through every answer and found no method using just the android and no root. (**USING ANDROID 11**)

1.) Using termux I installed the android-tools package which is very easy folliwng termux's wiki.

2.) open settings -> Wireless Debugging: and toggle on wireless debugging

3.) click Pair device with paring code.

4.) Enable split screen with the settings app and termux. In termux (with settings app still open) enter the command adb pair ip:port (the port here is what you see in the split screen above)

5.) it will ask you for a code, again use what you see split screen settings app.

6.) in termux enter the command adb connect ip:port (make sure the port is the one you see above as it may be different from the last one you just entered)

The entire process can be done automatically using tasker I wont post that here as I've found it quick and easy to do it manually, but the creator of tasker has a guide out there somewhere on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code .bat cmd on windows, this code is for future snippt.

```
@echo off
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload

::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW::   
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 193.169.4.2:5555



::END OF YOUR CODE::

echo.
echo...Script Complete....
echo.

pause
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `adb shell ip -f inet addr show wlan0` to find the device ip after `adb tcpip 5555`.

Newer version deprecated adb netcfg. Thus this is the correct way to find the ip of the device when the interface name is wlan0 (default interface name).

Answer (score -3):

That is too much simple...

Step 1:

```
connect mobile to laptop (PC)
find adb path in Eclipse or Go Tast manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) -> process -> adb.exe -> right-click -> open file location -> copy the path of the open window (like D:\.....)
```

Step 2:

```
open cmd and change directory like C:, D:, E:, and G:
 1: C:\Users\UMT>D:
 2: D:\> cd (past path of adb) like (ANDROID eclipse\Eclipse Setup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-202\sdk\plat-form-tools) and press enter
 3: Then type `adb tcpip 5555`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> ... make sure your mobile connects to the PC
```

Step 3:

```
Open new cmd and same above, go to the adb directory and type
adb connect 192.168.x.x(device ip):5555
press enter now connect it.
```

Device IP address: Setting -> About phone -> Status -> IP address