# Debugging in Android device over wifi without rooting

Tags: android, adb

Is there any possible way to debug or run android apps from eclipse to my Sony Tablet S over wifi rather than USB without rooting the device?

There are ways to do it, if the device is rooted. However, I am seeking the solution in a device that is not rooted.

Comment: Unless Sony has published something specific for that device, you are limited to debugging over USB. The only non-rooted devices that support debugging over a network are Google TV devices, AFAIK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938/209103

Comment: Please check [android document ][1] to debug over wifi


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Disconnect device from usb then tell it to listen on 4455

  **adb tcpip 4455**

restarting in TCP mode port: 4455

- connect to the device using a specified ip:port. my device is using wifi

  **adb connect 192.168.1.103:4455**

connected to 192.168.1.103:4455

- now do normal adb commands over tcp like

  **adb shell**
- when your done, you can put it back in USB mode
  adb usb
  restarting in USB mode

Comment: As stated in the other reply (and error mesage for that matter), the device needs to be connected via usb when using the first command.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks alot .... I used to run ADB debug Android App with rooted mobile ... u made my day :)

Comment: @Hefny You are welcome. Keep debugging!! :)

Answer (score 11):

After a bit of dabbling with testing I successfully managed to connect a Sony Tablet S over ADB following this procedure, when both the computer and the tablet were on the same wifi network. I used an Xperia T as a tethering point between a laptop and the Tablet S. I followed the same procedure on an Xperia Tablet S and an Xperia S as well.

1. Connect the Sony Tablet S through USB to a computer, make sure you have ADB debugging enabled on the tablet.
2. On the computer, execute "adb devices", verifying the tablet is showing up in the list of available devices.
3. Execute "adb tcpip [port]" while the tablet is connected to the computer, verifying you get a response "restarting in TCP mode port: [port]"
4. Disconnect from the device from the computer it was connected to.
5. From a host located on the same wifi network, execute "adb connect [ip to device]:[port]", verifying you get a response "connected to [ip to device]:[port]"

In the end I launched Eclipse, created a test project and tried launching the project. The project installed and launched automatically from Eclipse. I also tested this for debugging and that worked equally well.

Answer (score 11):

Finally After lots of search, here is the consolidated, short tutorial about "**Wireless Debugging with Android** ***without rooting***" your android phone.

**Steps:**

1. Make sure your Phone and your PC/Laptop is connected in the same network.
2. **Find your Android Device's IP Address:** Go to *Settings > About Phone > Status*. Note down it.
3. **Ping Test:** Lets first check if your phone is accessible from your PC/Laptop to do this `ping` your Android Device and check its response. See *Notes* if ping is unsuccessful.

> `e.g: ping 192.168.1.55`

4. Connect your Android Device Via USB in USB Debugging Mode.
5. Open command prompt and `cd` into `<Android SDK Folder>\platform-tools` directory and run the following commands.

> ```
> adb tcpip 5555
> adb connect DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_HERE:5555
> ```

6. If you want to switch back to USB mode, use the following command.

> `adb -s DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_HERE:5555`

Disconnect Android Device from USB. If everything is fine, you can Wirelessly debug your Android Apps!

***Notes:***

- If ping is unsuccessful, Make sure Wireless (WiFi) devices and wired devices are not ***isolated***. If Isolated, you need to disable isolation. Router Mfgrs calls it as ***AP Isolation***. There will be a setting in Router's Wireless Configuration page. I have D-Link Router, I unchecked the **Enable MultiAP Isolation** setting in *Wireless Basic Setup* Page.
- ***I personally felt this method of connecting is taking more time..*** so, I configured my android device so it uses static IP like 192.168.1.55 to connect to my router and I made a windows batch file like below,

> ```
> @echo off
> cd C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\
> echo make sure your your Phone is connected in USB Debugging Mode.
> pause
> adb kill-server
> adb tcpip 5555
> adb connect 192.168.1.55
> pause
> ```

so, every time I have just need to plug in my device, and double click the batch file and all done automatic :P !

Comment: I was thinking to make batch file, but after scrolling to end, i found this answer. It helped. Good one

Answer (score 4):

*(No root required)* There is one best, easy and with UI method for Android Studio

IntelliJ and Android Studio plugin created to quickly connect your Android device over WiFi to install, run and debug your applications without a USB connected. Press one button and forget about your USB cable.

just install plugin **Android WiFi ADB**

Download and install Android WiFi ADB directly from

Intellij / Android Studio: **Preferences/Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories**

[image]

[image]

.

**Remember!** for first time to initialize the device you must have to connect using usb

Alternatively, you can download the plugin from the JetBrains plugin site and install it manually in: **Preferences/Settings->Plugins->Install plugin from disk.**

for more information read here  https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB