# Permanently connect android device and eclipse over wifi

Tags: android, eclipse, wifi, adb

Is there any way to permanently connect android device with eclipse via wifi. 
Adb connect ********* works but only till I continually use my wifi network, what if I want to take a break and start coding after a while.

Comment: @Hi-Tech KitKat Android of course it can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: It's simple and supposedly work go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi just simple 4 steps

Comment: Hey, check this http://slomin.blogspot.in/2012/06/easy-way-to-debug-your-android-apps.html

Comment: @ balakrishnan it works only on rooted device as it says. And i think many people dont want ro root there device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theoretically you can do it.**

On the Android device:
Never disable adb over the WiFi.

On the development machine:
You need to connect to your Android device every time you are restarting your development machine. So you need to run a shell on boot with a simple line : 
adb connect x.x.x.x

P.S.: Of course you need to check if your Android device is available and connected to the home network, anyway what is the problem of just typing once / twice a day adb connect?