# IntelliJ, how to use ADB over network (wifi)

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, adb

How can I use adb over network in IntelliJ IDE, is there any article for learning how configure IntelliJ to use adb over network? I need it so much

Comment: You don't need to configure IntelliJ.  Just install "ADB Wifi" or a similar app on your phone.  Then connect using `adb connect`

Comment: my rom is CM and ADB over network is enable on it, and i have my connecting Ip, but i don't know how can i start debugging from pc !

Comment: I don't know how to say it more clearly.  There is no configuration in IntelliJ.  It has no way of knowing, and no need to know, how ADB is connected.  Just install an app, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&hl=en, then use "adb connect" on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options for this, try one of the following links:

http://stuffandtech.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html

[Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi)