# Phonegap don't see Sony Xperia Z1 on devices list

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap application (for Android). When I plug my Xperia Z1 to my PC (which runs Ubuntu 13) it shows only install disk (some exe'cs are there) and don't show on devices list (I have also turned on debugging usb feature etc.) - I think this can be caused by lack of drivers for this phone (and I can't find anywhere drivers for ubuntu for Sony Xperia Z1).

In addition Eclipse shows only "????" as a device name and cannot run my app with that position chosen. Please help.

UPDATE:

I've found this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39893/how-to-access-the-sd-card-through-my-sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-phone but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Warlock read the question again!

Answer (score 1):

> (I have also turned on debugging usb feature etc.) - I think this can
>   be caused by lack of drivers for this phone (and I can't find anywhere
>   drivers for ubuntu for Sony Xperia Z1).

Yes, you are right. The OS doesn't recognize the phone, can't communicate with him via USB port.

I would install a Virtual machine on Linux and a windows on it, until  I could find a workaround or a driver released.

Comment: that's bad :/ is there any 'replacement' usb driver maybe available (e.g. for similiar phone etc.) ?

Comment: I don't think is a good idea... you can crash a few times the OS. If you modify the Preloader at your phone, than you can brick your phone: it will lot even turn on!

Comment: no no I thought about usb drivers that I could install at Ubuntu, not phone ;)

Comment: I have installed a couple of other drivers, when  I didn't got the driver needed. With some just doesn't work and nothing happens. With other can be a bad situation. Let say the driver it says to receive 8 bytes and you send only 4, than somebody will wait for long for other 4 bytes... in other case SegmentationFault, or a king a windows blue screens. I better play inn sand with what I have... instead of installing bad drivers and than installing OS, recovering data...because  I havn't anything better to do.  Thats why I told to move to other OS, where are drivers

Answer (score 1):

You can build and run to mobile over wifi, but I'm afraid you need the driver first to setup see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi)