# Is it possible to test an app via AirDroid rather than having the device plugged in?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

I don't want to have to constantly plug in and unplug my device whenever I need to test and app. Is it possible to use AirDroid to run an app from Eclipse to my device without having to root the device?

Sorry if this question has been asked and answered, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Run/install/debug applications over WiFi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello :) There are four options for you to run your project:

1. On your android device when plugged to the computer and USB debugging is on.
2. On your computer using emulator like - Eclipse emulator, Bluestacks, and more.
3. Go to your project folder -- > bin -- > move the APK file to your device and run.
4. See here : [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi)

The fourth answer is just for you :)

--- To find your device IP address go to Wifi settings - hit the 3 vertical dots and tap advanced Wifi settings -- IP address.

Comment: Thank you for providing a root-free solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to root your device, install WiFi ADB from Play market, run the Wifi Adb and switch it on. Then run the displayed command in command line.

Example:

```
C:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb connect 192.168.0.3:5555
```