# ADB TCPIP Connecting trouble

Tags: android, adb, tcp

I have two Galaxy S3. One of them is rooted and the other one is not. So, when I tried to connect them over the local network, computer can see the rooted one. But normal one stucks on the tcpip step. So, I write

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

It says

```
restarting in TCP mode port : 5555
```

but nothing else. Can you help me with these?

Note: My OS is Win8.

Answer (score 1):

After running

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

What is the ouput when you try to run the "connect" command to the devices based on knowing the IP of the phone e.g.

```
adb connect 192.168.1.186
```

should result in something like:

```
connected to 192.168.1.186:5555
```

Also, make sure you have USB debugging turned on on the Samsung 'Settings' --> 'Developer options'

(If you don't see 'Developer Options', you'll need to enable it first ([link](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=How%20to%20enable%20developer%20options%20on%20Andoid&oq=How%20to%20enable%20developer%20options%20on%20Andoid&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8343j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=How%20to%20enable%20developer%20options%20on%20Android&spell=1)))

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small script for myself

1. Simply Connect your device (in USB debugging mode).
2. Go to location **"C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"**
3. Press Shift + Right Click --> open Command window here.
4. Paste that script there , make sure adb.exe is available at that path in PC.
5. run **wireless.bat** follow steps give your IP that's it.

[wireless.bat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2A29bvGdA4EWDlvNHluMXMxcWM)