# Android Studio - Device is connected but 'offline'

Tags: android-studio, adb

This is quite a common question, but none of the solutions appear to work for me. First time asker, so apologies if I get the conventions wrong.

I am trying to connect my Galaxy S5 to my computer running Ubuntu 14.04 so I can do some android development. I have recently downloaded and installed Android Studio and the SDK and my device is detected when it's connected via USB but the device either appears as 'unauthorized' or 'offline'. I know I should be expecting the RSA key prompt but this never appears.

I have tried:

- Checking debugging was enabled
- Running adb kill-server and adb devices
- Restarting (the device, developer options, the machine)
- Simple unplugging and replugging the USB cable
- Checking my adb version (it is 1.0.31)
- Trying different USB ports
- Revoking USB debugging authorizations
- Toggling enabling ADB Integration from within Android Studio
- Connecting as PTP device and MTP device

I have tried it on a separate machine that runs fedora and this works fine with no issues, the promopt appears right away. Therefore I imagine it is not the USB cable that is faulty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12664045/675383) help?

Comment: @nhaarman I hadn't tried that, thanks. Just followed the instructions and it still does not work

Comment: install padNet+ and restart your device as well as android studio.

Comment: I hate android studio. For no reasons it suddenly started to show me this when my device was surely connected.

Answer (score 171):

Try these:

- Unplug and replug the USB cable.
- If it still doesn't work, unplug the USB cable, disable then enable USB debugging in the device settings.
- If the above two methods fail, reboot the device.
- If rebooting the device also fails, reboot Android Studio too.
- If reboot Android Studio still fail, try `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`.

Comment: Rebooting the device was the working option for me. Thanks

Comment: My device is **wifi adb**, not usb

Comment: You can try to reenable developer mode if measures above-mentioned don't work.

Comment: I just wonder why such heavily used and basic feature, made by one of the biggest developer (Google) is so unstable?

Comment: @PolGraphic its not google, but the companies that build the phones' hardware. Google made the OS, but its up to manufacturers to have compatible chips that can work with the OS.

Comment: Also try using different USB ports

Answer (score 48):

Try killing adb `adb kill-server`then disable usb debugging and then start adb by `adb start-server` then enable usb debugging and plug phone again and huh don't let phone sleep between process

**EDIT**

> There turned out to be a problem with my laptop's ADB RSA key. I'm assuming my G3 was rejecting a bad key and disallowing my laptop to connect to it via ADB.
>
> ADB saves a key file in one of multiple places on a Windows computer, the first is in the location where adb.exe is (C:\android), the second is in the user's >profile (C:\Users*username*.android), the third place is in the Windows system files (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.android), the file is >simply named "adbkey" with no extension. If there is no key file when ADB runs, it will generate one automatically.
>
> Mine was located in my user folder (C:\Users*username*.android). All I had to do was delete the adbkey file (there was also a file named "adbkey.pub" which >I deleted as well), restart the adb server in command prompt (adb start-server) and plug my phone in. I instantly received the RSA Fingerprint Key window on my >G3 allowing connection between the two devices. Then typing "adb devices" returned my phone's serial number followed by "device" showing it was available. >I went back to the C:\Users*username*.android\ folder and sure enought there were new "adbkey" and "adbkey.pub" files.

got from XDA

**EDIT 2**

TRY this steps too

1. Navigate to where .android is stored
2. open .android and delete file named as adbkey and adbkey.pub
3. Start ADB then type`adb kill-server`and `adb start-server`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this and the RSA prompt still doesnt appear

Comment: try switching mtp to ptp or ptp to mtp

Comment: Thanks. where do I locate .android? I cant seem to locate them. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, so not sure how your solution maps to it.

Comment: Where project is located

Answer (score 19):

My fix to this issue:

1. Android settings
2. Developer options
3. Revoke USB debugging authorizations
4. Replug in device and accept authorization as usual.
5. Profit

Comment: Great. Seams the simplest and most straight forward solution. Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Step 1: Turn off USB DEBUGGING in Developer Options

Step 2: Remove USB Cable

Step 3: Turn on USB Debugging(This rests USB Configurations)

Step 4: on Command Prompt enter adb kill-server and then adb start-server

Step 5: Connect the USB Cable

Step 6: Check Devices connected in Run in Android Studio(you should be able to see your device listed)

Step 7: If you want to continue running using the cable this would be good enough

(If you want to do Wireless Debugging continue with below step)

Step 8: type adb tcpip 5555. If no error is displayed remove USB Cable

Step 9: Look up IP Address of your phone from About abd then type adb connect xxx.vvv.b.n(your phone's IP)

Step 10: Check in Devices in Android Studio again and you shud see you r device in List of devices. If yes,

Comment: THIS!! The For me, the important part turned out to be the following line ````adb tcpip 5555```` **together with** using the port in the IP of my phone like so: ````adb connect 192.168.1.87:5555````. I tried them on their own first. Like using the tcpip command and leaving out the port in the connect command, or having the port in the connect command and leaving out the tcpip command. No go. BOTH needs to be there.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on windows and you encountered the same problem, try killing the `adb.exe` process from task manager and then rerun your app.

Answer (score 6):

Change the USB cable !!!!
I can't explain this technically, however after a lot of trial and error, this what have worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Could not get Samsung Note II (N7100) to connect.

Step 1. Follow answer from [user4847410](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019937/user4847410) above. Next time you connect your phone it will come up with an authorisation message and you're in.

Step 2. I also swapped my cable.

Step 3. Check USB port as if you install on one particular port then another port may not be ok for you.

Note: made two batch files

adb-fix.bat

```
adb kill server
adb start server
pause
```

adb-devices.bat

```
adb devices
pause
```

-- voted for that correct answer but I don't have enough kudos so it was removed! --

Comment: What is `pause`?

Comment: It makes the Windows shell wait for a keystroke.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, use USB2 instead of USB3

Answer (score 4):

A shorter cable did the trick.

> It turns out that the wire thickness used inside the cable impacts on the resistance of the cable assembly – this resistance causes energy loss inside the cable when an attached load draws a current, and causes a voltage drop which can reduce the voltage to the end device to a point where it is not possible to charge quickly or completely.

http://goughlui.com/2014/10/01/usb-cable-resistance-why-your-phonetablet-might-be-charging-slow/

Comment: Indeed! My 1 meter cables always work, my new 1.5 meter cable does not.

Comment: Can't believe this solved my issue!

Answer (score 4):

Change your USB Preferences to File Transfer if you use your smartphone to debug.

There are several option :

File Transfer /* Choose this one */

USB Tethering

MIDI

PTP

No Data Transfer

Comment: This was the only thing I had to do in addition to following the guide https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-connect-device#2 to connect a freshly set up Pixel 4a.

Answer (score 3):

I had a long white cable.  Just wouldnt stay connected. Switched to another, shorter, black cable and it works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling and Enabling the Developer options and debug mode on the Android phone settings fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier for almost 3hrs I did:

1. I tried everything given in several sites and my android device never came online.
2. when I was running adb kill-server and then adb-startserver the "Device File Explorer" on the right bottom of the android studio showed "Device is not online (DISCONNECTED)".

Here is how solve this:

1. Revoked all USB debugging authorization on the device under "Develop options"
2. And I added sudo to command "sudo adb kill-server" and then " sudo adb start-server".
3. After this the message in "Device File Explorer" in android studio changed to "device is pending authentication please accept debugging session on the device". But no message appeared on the device. Tried stopping-restarting adb, connect reconnet usb cable, stop-start usb debugging but nothing worked.
4. Went back to device and changed the device usb settings from usb charging to "PTP", and, restarted the Android studio. And, boom, the message appeared on the phone to accept the debugging session on device.

Answer (score 3):

use this command

```
-> adb disconnect

-> adb connect <ip address for your mobile:port number>
```

**Eg : adb connect 192.168.2.58:5555**

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. Go to `tools/enable adb integration` and uncheck it.
2. now check it and run again. Next time, android studio will restart adb and it may find your device.

Comment: Thanks. This has not worked either. The device is still listed as offline

Answer (score 2):

- Restart adb by issuing these commands in cmd

   `adb kill-server` to kill existing adb session 
   followed by `adb start-server` to start a new adb session
- Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone and accept RSA fingerprints if asked by phone
- Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.

If all above don't solve your problem, you may try delete environment variable named "`ANDROID_SDK_HOME`".
It really solved my problem. Hope it Help you!

Answer (score 2):

This fixed for me

uncheck launch in tool windo

[image]

Source

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/76#issuecomment-1023563846

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you have used an old adb version and not support on your device. or you have more than one adb

The key is:

- make sure you have a latest adb executable on your SDK
- Make sure to run adb command from "SDK_DIR/platform-tools/" because this should be the latest version (type command "which adb" to check) if u have more than one adb file, you can rename another one.

in my case, on my Windows 7 i have one more adb on "C:\Windows\adb.exe" and its an old version, so my adb command always run from that file. I fixed the problem by running adb form my sdk directory "SDK_DIR/platform-tools/adb.exe"

Answer (score 1):

On windows--> Launch your terminal from the platform-tools folder inside android sdk.

Then use the following commands

```
adb kill server
adb start server
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade your Android SDK Platform as below steps:

1. Run the SDK Manager
2. Execute "Install packages…"
3. Restart the SDK Manager

I tried and it's ok for me.

ref: [link](https://hedgehogjim.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/android-adb-reports-device-is-offline/)

Comment: Add here more information. The link can become unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe having an older version of the ADB, Update the tools package and that should bring down the latest ADB.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently had this problem and I solved it by rebooting Android Studio. But my friend had to have the original cable for his device, no other cables worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (same problem - that Nexus 5 is connected but with "offline" status) the problem was solved by "Invalidate caches and Restart" in Android Studio.
Suppose that problem was in adb and restarting Android Studio causes to adb restart.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install your device driver manually through visiting manufacturer website like :Samsung,micromax,intex etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I used a USB extension cable. As soon as I plug the microUSB cable right into the PC the device has detected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, turned out that you need to be logged as owner of device to properly accept the USB debugging.

Tried the "Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone" step but didn't get the RSA prompt on "normal" user, switched to owner and tried again and got it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a device with USB-C using a microUSB cable with a USB-C adapter. After switching to a USB-C cable without any adapter it worked. I only saw this issue on a LeEco.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the things on this page and none of them worked for my Samsung S5. However, when I switched the cable to a USB-C type the problem seemed to be solved...until next time.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution mentioned above, try to download Samsung's Android USB Driver for your platform. Here is a link to the Windows one:

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't manipulate WiFi connections - another slightly different solution, which bypasses USB issues entirely - enabling a [wireless debugging connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663246/use-adb-over-tcpip-in-android-studio) - ADB over WiFi/TCP/IP.

Answer (score -2):

Reboot the your mobile this will fix it.