# Android Studio Device Offline While Plugged In

Tags: android, android-studio, connection, galaxy

I have tried EVERYTHING I could find on this but still no solution. 
I have a Samsung s6 edge Plus 32 GB. I am trying to deploy an app on Android Studio but it always shows the device as offline. What I have tried

- Unplugging and plugging back
- Restarting device
- Enabling debugging on device
- Shuffled and tried different transfer protocols
- Installing and Uninstalling Samsung drivers
- Checking 'Enable ADB integration' under Tools -- Android
- Checking android studio & driver updates

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964854/android-studio-device-is-connected-but-offline

Answer (score 3):

This happens sometime, even when USB Debugging is on. Try this:

1. Go to Settings->Developer Options
2. Search for Revoke USB Debugging Devices
3. Revoke all existing devices
4. Disable USB Debugging and enable it
5. Now connect your phone to system with USB cable
6. Wait, and a dialog will appear on your phone, for permission to allow for USB Debugging. Click on checkbox and press Allow.
7. Now the device should appear online in Android Studio.
8. If problem still persists, then problem is with your phone drivers installed on system.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me regularly (I use multiple devices) and one of these two things always fixes it:

1. Make sure your device has "only charge" selected in the dropdown menu entry that appears when you connect your phone. Instead select "transfer files".
2. Disable and enable usb debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Change your device cable or change your connection USB port on PC. I think this problem is hardware problem. Try other hardware problem possibilities.