# My device go offline and shows offline react native but connected to laptop

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on react native and my device goes offline after a few minutes automatically.
using command (adb devices) it shows

```
List of devices attached
8BG7S16202003644        offline
```

but my device is connected to my laptop.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257704/7704650)

Comment: I think there was some issue with the cable , I change the cable and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Check your cable! If it is showing the device that was connected earlier then your cable is not working! Had same issue but resolved after changing the cable!