# How to debug(play) Unity 5 for Gear VR without having it transferred to the phone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I made things in Unity 5 for Gear VR.

When I connect Galaxy S6 and on Unity, do

```
 File -> Build and Run
```

The phone tells me to connect the phone with Gear VR, and after doing that everything works fine.

But when i press Play from Unity, Unity itself crashes and closes itself.

So i have to download and debug on the phone everytime i want to debug, which takes so much time.

So there any easy way of debugging unity for gear vr on mac?

Answer (score 2):

you might not be able to debug using Unity (like Unity profiler, etc), but you can use Android studio or `adb` to debug it, so everytime you do `Debug.Log` and its family, they will be printed into the log just filter it with `Unity` keyword.

Since using cable is unfeasible for GearVR, you need to use `adb` with TCP/IP i.e. using wireless. There are a lot of articles on how to use `adb` wifi, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663246/use-adb-over-tcpip-in-android-studio)

Hope this helps