# Vue.js WebStorm remote Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm, remote-debugging, remote-server

How can I config WebStom IDE to start Vue.js app remotely without connecting manually to npm trough SSH terminal (`npm run dev`)?

I'm developing my first Vue.js/JavaScript app and my development server is a Raspberry Pi, because I want to collaborate with a friend on this project.
For this moment we are stucked on this step. We already configured WebStorm to auto-download/auto-upload files to the server but we can't start the Vue.js project from it.

Comment: You can look into this question [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session). Basically keeping `npm run dev` running on the Pi, even if you log out. So there won't be any need to start it every time...Also, I would recommend using GIT for collaboration, because sooner or later, when both of you edit same file, one of you will loose it's changes/updates

Comment: What if your friend already started the app? Would you both have to call (text) each other whenever one of you starts/stops the app?

Comment: If this is a collaboration, then there is no need to share a single instance of the server for development. A local development server should work just fine as long as you both have a way of sharing the source code (aka VC). You should push to server when the app is mature enough for deployment. In which case you wouldn't need to "start" the app because the server should be configured to automatically start the app when a new version is deployed.

Comment: I made something like this but for android studio (which is a Jetbrains derivative). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663246/use-adb-over-tcpip-in-android-studio/37874678#37874678). The idea here is to make a tool that will prompt you for the PI's address and it will automatically ssh and run the command on the pi. The syntax for running remote ssh commands is `ssh USER@HOST 'COMMAND'`