# View logcat whilst not debuggin

Tags: android, logcat

I'm developing an application that communicates with another device over usb, the problem is this makes it quote difficult to debug because I can't connect it to my PC at the same time. Is there a way of getting at the logcat out at a later date. That is, I have a bunch of log.d statements, I'm hoping I can run my app, and then afterwards connect it to my PC to download the resulting log statements?

Regards

Dan

Comment: Get a USB hub perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick to have adb debugging while doing USB communication is to use adb tcpip

Comment: Thanks that sounds like a good idea. Do you have a link to a tutorial? I've had a quick Google but can only find hits about people with connection problems

Comment: I got one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi