# adb connection in Android with multiple system

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have one Android phone device and I want to run my android application from two different windows pc with eclipse. How it possible to run an android application in one device from two different eclipses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible to run an android application in one device from
>   two different eclipses?

You cannot connect one device to multiple pc through port but you can connect your device through Wifi and run application from two different pc. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi) explains how to connect through wifi