# Connect Android Studio to device via LAN

Tags: android, android-studio, debian, adb

I am using Debian 8.1, Android Studio 1.2.2 and a rooted Android TV Box with Android 4.2.2

Now I am trying to connect the TV Box to Android Studio via LAN, to directly test the app that I am developing.

My PC and the Android Box are in the same network. Also I can connect to the box in the Linux-console via:

```
adb connect 192.168.50.104
```

It says:

```
connected to 192.168.50.104:5555
```

I can fully access the Android TV Box via adb commands in the console.

But unfortunately Android Studio does not find the device... When I try to compile the app, Android Studio gives me the "Chooser Dialog", where I can Launch the Emulator, or choose a running device. But "running devices" says "nothing to show"

What is the problem?

UPDATE 1:
This is the device btw:
http://www.geniatech.com/pa/atv1200.asp

UPDATE 2:
in Windows it works perfectly! Adb connect 192.168.50.104 and voila! The device is shown in the list in Android Studio...

Comment: try to reset adb with `adb kill-server` and then re-estabilish the connection

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Still "Nothing to show" in Android Studio

Comment: Have you disconnected the device from USB? Before connecting via tcpip, you need to disconnect USB.

Comment: I am not connected to the Android Box via USB. (Never was ;) )

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi

Comment: Thank You, but I cannot connect the Android TV Box via USB, like it is described in the link. It does not have any USB Slave-ports (I mean it only has USB Type-A ports, which i cannot connect to the USB Type-A ports on my PC). Besides... in Windows it works perfectly without connecting it via USB first. Just "adb connect IP" and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

On the linux system I renamed the adb that came with the package-manager

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo mv adb backup_adb
```

Then I created a symlink to the adb, that is provided with the Android Studio SDK:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
```

Restart adb and reconnect to the device and it finally shows up in Android Studio.

Instead of renaming the adb-file you could probably just remove it, with your package manager.