# Android : debugging app over different network

Tags: android, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug app over diffrent networks. Is it possible.
I have tried wifi debugging where both the devices are connected to the same network (same wifi connection). As descripbed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi).

But whem i tried to do same steps, and using the different network connections, it didn't connect. I used the IP address of device while connecting it to different network.

[image]

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the device? Or access to a machine connected to the same network as the device?