# Android adb wireless/WIFI debug Operation timed out

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb, android-wifi

I followed steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/android-run-install-debug-applications-over-wifi) and tried to connect to my Motorola X Gen 2 for Wifi debugging, on OS X El Cap.

I connected my phone to the laptop with usb cable,
I killed and started server, the server was started successfully, and then in:

```
./adb devices
```

I got

```
List of devices attached
TA44909GA0  device
```

Then I did

```
./adb tcpip 5555
```

And I tried

```
./adb connect <IP addr of my phone>:5555
```

both with usb cable connected and disconnected, none of them worked. Both returned error message saying:

```
unable to connect to ***.***.***.***:5555: Operation timed out
```

I cannot figure out what is happening here, I tried the Android Studio plugin ADB WIFI, which returned the same message, operation timed out. I restarted everything, tried connecting with a different cable and all, nothing worked.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: make sure that `AP isolation` is off on your wifi router

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, it worked once, just once, the day before, and the next day it went back to "operation timed out". (And I am using my school wifi, so probably the setting didn't change)

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Not net. Restarting ./adb and phone and wait for a couple of hours would get it to work for a while. I'm suspecting it's hardware problem. Probably not good for this site...

Comment: Really, "adb reboot" (will restart your device) worked for me.

Comment: Make sure you are not in any VPN network

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Same network, not on VPN, restarted adb, restarted phone, still nothing. I'm not sure about AP isolation, but I'll live with the intermittent usb for now and focus on the app

Comment: @AA_PV It's better not to use it with a router that has a firewall itself, e.g. those ones that you need admin password to log in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure your computer and the android device are using the same wifi network. I had the same issue and fixed it after changing to the same wifi.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14659138)

Comment: @R.Zagórski this seems like an answer *"your computer and the android device needs to use the same wifi network"*

Answer (score 5):

So after a huge number of trials, I think the problem is somehow wifi related, I think this feature does not work well with WPA2 (or any kind of?) Enterprise encryption, because I was using my school Wifi, and it turned out to be okay, up and running, for the hotspot I set up with another laptop.

Comment: same thing happened to me.. my machine and device were connected to different wifi routers in my home.. =) =P

Comment: I have one router at home and both my MBP and FireTV are connected to the same SSID, but I could neither ping the IP or connect via adb. When I had both connect to my mobile hotspot, it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

What solved this for me:

- disconnect the phone from USB cable
- restart the phone
- reconnect the phone by USB cable

(meanwhile):

- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`

Then follow the "standard" procedure.

Comment: Just the kill/start on it's own is often enough

Comment: tried similar things but not working

Answer (score 2):

If you are connected on same network and still can't connect then check your IP twice . Sometimes it get changed.
check your IP = phone settings -> About phone -> Status -> IP address

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the timeout in Android Device Monitor.

From Android Studio: Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor
In Android Device Monitor:
Window->Preferences, Android->DDMS.

In the DDMS window, increase the "ADB Connection Timeout (ms)".  It defaults to 5000ms.  If your app is particularly large/takes a long time to load, it may go longer than this timeout, so increasing may fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mac OS.

Check by clicking on the wifi icon in the toolbar. If there is any warning.

In my case there was a warning saying the wifi is using WPA protocol and its not secure.

I went to my router settings and changes the protocol to WPA2/WPA3 auto.

After that the warning went away and the wireless debugging started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out its WiFi related.
When i reconnect my laptop to my WiFi network adb connected instantly.