# How to debug Android 6.0 over Wi-Fi? (netcfg issue)

Tags: android, wifi, adb

I am currently with a problem to debug Android 6.0 over Wi-Fi. I followed the steps of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938/2689473), however when I try the command **adb shell netcfg** I receive "/system/bin/sh: netcfg: not found". In addition, even the graphical option **ADB over network** in *Developers Options* Menu has disappeared.

I also, tried this [post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200882) of Android's Issue because *netcfg* seems to be deprecated, and I got: WFSO timed out.

It works fine before I updated to Android 6.0.

Does someone knows another command or way to debug over Wi-Fi?

Thanks in advance

---

**Solution**

Use `adb shell ifconfig <interface name>` as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36298875/2689473) from Rilwan to find out the IP address of the device. Then use `adb connect <ipaddress>`to finally debug over Wi-Fi. The real problem was just the missing *netcfg* command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your question, if you tried this over wifi means- `adb shell netcfg I receive "/system/bin/sh: netcfg: not found"`,  adb over wifi is working fine. Only problem is `netcfg` binary is not there in Android 6.0. If you have any other previous version android, you can pull `netcfg` binary and push to 6.0 device.

If you just want to know ipaddress you can use `adb shell ifconfig <interface name>`

Comment: Nice tip Rilwan, thank you.
I just got the IP address using `adb shell ifconfig` and I used `wlan0`as interface name (if no interface is used as parameter, all interfaces' details is showed). 
After that I just disconnected my device from the USB and used the command `adb connect <ipaddress>` as final step and it works.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, how can I get which interface name to pass.

Comment: Hi @Dory, if you just use `adb shell ifconfig` without any interface name it will show all interfaces and generally it is the `wlan0` that you are interested.

Comment: What is an interface name?

Comment: interface name is name of your wlan interface. for example in my case it is  `adb shell ifconfig wlan0`

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for IP address- your system and mobile are connected to the same network

Simply go to Settings -> About Phone -> Status

Here you will find the IP

Answer (score 2):

I use ADBWIFI plugin for android studio
[ADBWIFI](https://github.com/layerlre/ADBWIFI) .

I have not tested on Android 6.0 but give it a try.

Comment: Hi Murali, I have tried this plugin either and still not working. When I took off the USB cable, I lost the Wi-Fi connection.
It is supposed to work as you can see on this [issue](https://github.com/layerlre/ADBWIFI/issues/7). 
However, I am having troubles to keep the connection.