# Testing my app on a physical device

Tags: android

How can I test my app on a physical device on the LAN when the android mobile is connected to the LAN through the WiFi?
No virtual emulator no usb connect?

[image]

Comment: Look here, should be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

Using android adb command you can achieve this. For using adb you have connect your physical device with your system at once with usb cable.Fallow this setp

1. Connect your Android device and adb host computer to a common Wi-Fi network accessible to both.
2. Connect the device to the host computer with a USB cable.
3. Go to folder adnroid sdk>platform-tools>
4. Set the target device to listen for a TCP/IP connection on port 5555. 
   $adb tcpip 5555
5. Find the IP address of the Android device. For example, on a Nexus device, you can find the IP address at Settings > About tablet (or About phone) > Status > IP address. Or, on an Android Wear device, you can find the IP address at Settings > Wi-Fi Settings > Advanced > IP address.
6. Connect to the device, identifying it by IP address. 
   $ adb connect 
   exp : $adb connect 192.168.10.20
7. Disconnect the USB cable from the target device.

Now you can test your app on a physical device on the LAN when the android mobile is connected to the LAN through the WiFi.

for more details http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html