# Debugging workflow with a Samsung GearVR

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, adb, remote-debugging

As I started working with the GearVR, I tried to deploy the app with the usb cable plugged into the GearVR case, which is not working for me. So I always unplugged the device and deployed directly connected to the phone. This is kind of annoying after a while so I thought wifi debugging is the solution, but it takes pretty long to deploy even small apps (more than 3 minutes).

1. Is there any solution to speed up wifi deployment
2. Is it possible to plug in the cable directly into the gearVR for debugging/deployment?

Comment: you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: I thought I made it clear, that it's working with wifi, but is extremely slow...I've followed this guide already.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, Samsung GearVR is an Android device. You can do this with cable and you should be using cables. To get this to work, you must

**1**. Install the Samsung GearVR driver on your computer.

**2**. Enable DEBUGGING from [Developer options](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungdeveloperconnection/developer-resources/gear-vr/apps-and-games/setup-windows-os.html).

To make sure that Unity will use cable for Samsung GearVR, it must be recognizable by Unity. Open command prompt with `cmd` the change your directory to `AndroidSDK\platform-tools` with `cd /d G:\AppDev\AndroidSDK\platform-tools`  . Replace `G:\AppDev\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` with your android SDK location. then type `adb devices`. If no device is found then Unity wont' recognize it. Reboot your computer and try it again.

Also look at the information here:
http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungdeveloperconnection/developer-resources/gear-vr/apps-and-games/setup-windows-os.html

[image]

Comment: Since I'm using a Mac I guess there is no driver needed, because I don't need any driver for normal android devices. And I've already tried `adb devices´ , which gives me just an empty list when the cable is plugged in the gearvr, if I plug out the phone and attach the cable to the phone everything works flawlessly.

Comment: I just read your link briefly and if I'm not missing anything even they write : "Connect your Samsung GALAXY Note 4 or S6/S6 Edge to your computer via USB cable.", which means even they don't attach the cable directly to the gearvr

Comment: @TobiasW That's the problem. You don't follow direction. "Note 4 or S6/S6 Edge to your computer via USB cable" means with cable. via  through. If it doesn't show up in the command line, it won't work. That's a fact and if you don't install driver, it wont show up either. You can stay there and keep complaining or you can follow the direction above. I may not reply to you again if you have not done every step. Good luck!

Comment: Did you read the question? It's working without problems like they describe it, my phone is connected via cable and I can deploy, BUT I can't deploy when the phone is inside the gearvr and I plug the cable into the gearvr slot . So the way like they describe it is working for me, but I don't want to unplug the phone each time I want to deploy my updated code.

Comment: And the driver installation part is missing in the Mac guide so I guess I don't need it like I said already.

Comment: You second to last comment makes sense.The first line of your question is misleading. Did I read your question? Yes. This is from your question "I tried to deploy the app with the usb cable plugged into the GearVR case, which is not working for me.". My first thought was that wifi is working but cable is not. That confused me.

Comment: Ways you can speed up your development: Select all your textures and change all their resolution to the lowest as you can. Only leave those you you need to see what they really look like. Go very close to the Router, and connect  your computer directly to the Router. This will  make sure that the network bar of your phone is full and not 1 or 2 bars. If possible, get a personal router for development and connect only your phone and your computer to it to make sure that no other requests are being handled by the router, from other devices.

Comment: You are right wifi is working and cable not, when the phone is plugged into the case. And thanks for the advices considering the network, but unfortunately I can't change anything there...

Comment: If you change the texture size, the file should be smaller when deploying and will speed up. For the network, what can't you change in the network stuff I said and why?