# What is the best way to debug an android application on a tablet WHILE having an external USB device connected to said tablet?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nfc, acr122

I am developing an application for the latest version of Android using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015 community. I haven an ACS122-U NFC reader connected to the tablet using USB On-The-Go. I'm able to interface with the reader, but due to the lower level nature of its libraries I'm having to slowly work my way through sending the correct commands. I'd like to have real-time debugging instead of message boxes with exception errors and response values.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I've tried connecting a powered USB dock to the tablet, reader, and PC but I'm sure that has no way of directing the information to the correct devices.

Comment: I believe you can debug over WiFi (should apply to Xamarin also) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Never would have thought of that.