# Android Studio debugger does not stop at breakpoints for ADB over TCP

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, wireless

I am trying to debug my android application on a device connected via local-network.

I have used following instructions to create ADB with device over TCP:
[Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi/10236938#10236938)

I can install the app and see the logs but
i can not debug the application because Android studio doesn't stop at any breakpoint.

Following is Debug console's log:

> Waiting for application to come online: com.example.tosc.notesync.test
> | com.example.tosc.notesync
>
> Connecting to com.example.tosc.notesync

Is it really possible to debug the android app line by line over wireless connection?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct device? How do you obtain the IP and what is the IP that you are using?

Comment: yes i am sure. When i start debugging, application does get started but most of time it stuck on "waiting for debugger". Once in a while it works, but at that time, it never stops on any break-point.

Comment: And i have obtained the IP address from settings >about tablet >status

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I've faced the same problem.