# Connecting android mobile to cloudly hosted Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

For my project. I have given by an android studio which is hosted on cloud server.

Normally, while we are developing android applications we are able to connect our real devices to the android studio and run it simply and test on real devices. But Unfortunately, I could not able to connect my real android device to the remotely hosted android studio.

Do we have any solution to connect our real device to remotely hosted android studio.

Comment: You can run adb through wifi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: while i am typing the command `adb tcpip 5555` It says no adb devices found. Actuall problem is server is hosted on cloud

Comment: I see. Try enabling ADB over Network. You'll see the IP of the phone + port. Go the the adb on the cloud, and type `adb connect <ip:port>` adb tcpip gives me the same error as you, but skipping that part. But instantly connecting works in my case.