# Is it possible to read some smartphone details without USB debugging enabled?

Tags: android, usb, usb-debugging

Does anybody know if it is possible to read the build number from a Samsung smartphone without USB debugging being enabled?
I searched the USB descriptors already but cannot find it.
Did I overlooked it or is it somewhere else?
Maybe with some kind of extra (vendor specific) usb communication?
Or is it just not possible?

Uwe.

Comment: without USB debugging enabled, the smartphone is just an MTP device for the PC. It even doesn't know if it is an MP3 player, a digital camera, or a mobile phone.

Comment: Ok. But it is possible to read the Manufacturer Info and the device id...
Why not the build number?

Comment: you can go through wifi, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: @eduyayo: Look at your link: "1. Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working."

Comment: you can also magically adjust those settings but I strongly recommend praying instead

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to be possible...
I just checked with Samsungs "Smart Switch". It shows the Android version and the software version being installed. Without USB debugging. Does anybody knows how Samsung gets these information? Otherwise I have to do a USB sniff.