# Connect device over Wi-fi

Tags: java, android, android-widget, adb

I can't connect my device using android  over wifi. How to use this ? Can anyone help me. I can connect my mobile IP to terminal but application can't run in device using android over wifi.

Comment: This is answered here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: there is a plugIn u can use..