# Run ionic project in android device without wired connection

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have tried to run my ionic v3.x project in android device without wired connection and i have fired this commands. path is /home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools.

```
./adb start-server
./adb devices
./adb tcpip 5555
./adb connect 10.42.0.130
```

my mobile is connected through same WiFi network and after this, I have run my ionic project to the mobile but following error has occurred.

```
Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

so please help me out what is the problem.
Thank you in advance and all suggestions are welcome

Comment: I think the following link will help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Comment: in that answer the option of ADB over network is suggested but it is not in my mobile

Comment: Are you saying that your device doesn't support ADB over network?