# Sending SMS from Debian via Android

Tags: android, debian, sms

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (Debian) and i hav also a Android Phone and i want to know if it's possible to execute command on debian's terminal for sending sms thourgh my Android via WI-FI.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:
https://gist.github.com/TotemaT/9a02628c1f69f885fe88

To connect the ADB through wifi, see the accepted answer here: 
[Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Comment: Ok, i'll dowload adb and i will test it and i will say if it's work