# How can I check my Logcat without being connected?

Tags: android, usb, logcat

I want to see the messages of Logcat without being connected. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure but try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your device with Wifi ADB once you connected with ADB remove the cable and you can run the app, debug code for this you need Wifi ADB plugin.

Go to `File>>Setting>>plugin>>>Browse Repositories`. after installing you can see you Wifi ADB at right side Bar.

Remember...Your system and your device should be on the same internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

By **without being connected**, if you mean without being connected via cable, there is option to connect to adb via wifi.

1.connect your device via USB

2.Then connect your device to WIFI and get the IP address(say 192.168.0.101). While still connect via usb type this in command line or via Android Studio Terminal

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555
```

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37669270/7360848) for details