# How to run Android emulator on network with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been debugging apps with built in android emulator which comes with Android Studio and It almost takes 10 mins to build the project since I have quite a low-end PC.

So I figured It would be easy If I could run emulator on different PC than Android Studio's, And somehow share their connection with network sharing. *(Is it even possible?)*

**For instance:** I have two PCs *(Lets say A and B)* on same network, both being potato PCs could manage to run android emulators without any additional load on system resources.
So what I want is to make PC-A run emulator and PC-B run Android Studio and by clicking on run, the app loads into the PC-A's emulator and I could see logs etc in PC-B's Android Studio.

I know I could build an apk and run it on different PC but I want to run it with debugging as well i.e LogCat etc.
Also, I don't want to use my real android device for testing purposes.

PS: I would gladly accept any alternatives etc.

Thankyou.

Comment: Check wifi debugging. Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi

Comment: @unedim Im aware of wifi debugging, but you cannot connect one pc to another using usb and enable wifi debugging with adb. Or Could you?

Comment: better run with your mobile it will help you