# How to connect device over wifi using ADB or Command Prompt

Tags: java, android

I am run command over cmd that working

```
adb that working

adb tcpip 5555
```

when throw adb connect its show failed to connect to 100.91.174.70:5555

even adb -l also shows me connected device list.

so where i did mistake never get if anyone have some problem or get solution please share.

Thanks in advence

Comment: your computer have access to the IP?

Comment: android studio -> preference -> plugins -> install Android Wifi ADB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Comment: `100.91.174.70` is that IP address of your phone? Are you sure that your mobile ISP  allows incomming connections?

Comment: @SurajGhadge #Vladyslav #Lingeshwaran Thank to all of you for your suggestion and concern :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your terminal path to platform-tools path which is in SDK.

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

2. Connect your device with USB.
3. After that add below line in the terminal.

-->for checking whether your device is connected or not

> adb devices

-->this gives you this kind of response if it is connected

> List of devices attached
>
> 9153c6a4 device

--> please be sure that your device and your computer connected to same wifi or network
--> after that write

> adb shell setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555

-->then press enter and write this

> adb tcpip 5555

-->press enter and get you device ip and add this line

> adb connect 192.168.0.1:5555
>
> 192.168.0.1 is my device ip

-->this connect your device using wifi

Answer (score 0):

Your device and PC both should be under same network.then only it will able to connect.

**E.g**

If your device is connected with mobile network and your PC use broadband internet then it will not work.

Comment: Hi Hardik thanks for respond i connect my pc and mobile same wifi but it couldn't work.

Comment: @AakarshRai : try "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server" and then try to connect

Comment: Thank you @hardik for help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. first set your terminal path to platform-tools path which is in SDK.
2. connect your device with USB
3. after that add below line in the terminal

-->for checking whether your device is connected or not

> adb devices

-->this gives you this kind of response if  it is connected

> List of devices attached
>
> 8053a4b6        device

--> please be sure that your device and your computer connected to same wifi or network
--> after that write

> adb shell setprop service.adb.tcp.port 1111

-->then press enter and write this

> adb tcpip 1111

-->press enter and get you device ip and add this line

> adb connect 192.168.0.1:4444

-->this connect your device using wifi