# I can't debug react-native through Wifi after following the instructions

Tags: android, react-native

I know that it has been asked many times.

I'm trying to debug a rect-native app through wifi because I need to connect an usb device to the phone.

I have followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi).

When I try to reload the app, I have the red screen:

[image: could not connect to development server]

However, When I put the URL in the browser, it works:

[image: React Native Packager is running]

Obviously I' missing something here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT: Saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938/15186). It allows me to install the app via Wifi but not to debug it :(, still have the red screen of death.

---

EDIT 2:

Tried to overcome the problem by fetching the bundle with curl and put it in the asset folder for it to be embedded. This part works but I still can't debug, this time I have more subtle error message:

Unable to connect with the remote debugger

CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.1.61 not permitted by network security policy.

which leads to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted).

**EDIT 3**: Solved by modifying the existing react native network config file

[image]

Comment: your phone shouled be connected to the same wifi as your computer

Comment: @AhmedRebai it is.

Comment: check your usb then , your device is connected or not , by running adb list

Comment: Did you try the command `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` ?

Comment: - Output `$ adb devices`?
- Did you set dev-server and port via dev settings?

Comment: @AhmedRebai The app has been installed via usb, now usb is disconnected.

Comment: @Onlinogame Yes I did that too.

Comment: @schogges Phone is no more connected via USB once the app has been installed.That is the point. Yes I set ip and port of the host via dev settings as explained in the instructions

Comment: Try to restart then your porject

Comment: Anyways your phone should be listed at `$ adb devices`. Did you do `$ adb tcpip 5555` and `$ adb connect <ip-of-your-phone>:5555`?

Comment: @schogges I did just now. adb devices is showing my phone. But the phone still can't connect to the dev server.

Comment: Ok maybe it helps if once your phone is connected and visible at `$ adb devices` with it's IP, run `$ react-native run-android` again. If there is still the error, restart bundler, delete the app, `$ react-native run-android` again to reinstall the app and don't forget to set your dev-server's ip and port through dev-settings again (like `192.168.x.x:8081`).

Comment: @schogges This is crazy, the app is correctly reinstalled on the phone via the network, but I can't still access the dev server when loading the JS bundle. Again launching a browser and using the specified URL works like a charm :(