# Read Native android Manifest merger failed (networkSecurityConfig)

Tags: android, react-native

Note: this is [a followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57570658/15186).
I'm trying to allow http traffic in the android manifest of a react native application.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/15186), I created a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.61</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and referenced it in the manifest, in the  element :

```
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

At compile time, I have the following error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@networkSecurityConfig value=(@xml/react_native_config) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:7-67
>       is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:17:7-67 value=(@xml/network_security_config).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-138 to override.

I tried the suggested workaround but the error is still here.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Use this:<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>

Comment: @Kabir I tried that, but it does not work : CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.1.61 not permitted by network security policy

Comment: Ok, I was unaware of an existing config file for react native https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827042/15186 Now this is working fine

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue.

For react native, i found that it already has ***react_native_config.xml*** at project/android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml

just add your domain in react_native_config.xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: you just saved my life. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
<application
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```