# React-native: How to fix TypeError: Network request failed [Fixed]

Tags: android, react-native, typeerror

I got `TypeError: Network request failed` when fetching data, I tried build on Android Studio emulator and physical device, it occur same issue. I had read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653269/read-native-android-manifest-merger-failed-networksecurityconfig) but the solution do not work for me. Here is my react-native project info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 90.45 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.0/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.22.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 32, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.3, 33.0.0, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841
    Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 18.0.2.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.10 => 0.71.10 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I have add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config"` to AndroidManifest.xml, but my react-native project does not have xml folder in `android/app/src/main`. Although I tried to create a folder and add `react_native_config.xml` in `android/app/src/main/xml`, however it shows following error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@networkSecurityConfig value=(@xml/react_native_config) from
AndroidManifest.xml:17:7-67 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:17:7-67 value=(@xml/network_security_config).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-13:19 to override.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Am I miss anything?

---

2023/06/28 update:
I found it was because debug/AndroidManifest.xml and main/AndroidManifest.xml do not have same user-permission configuration, makes manifest merger failure. I copy all user-permission to debug/AndroidManifest.xml and it works now.