# Pair computer and phone with USB cable once, and then always use ADB over WiFi, even after reboot

Tags: android, adb, wifi

I'm using [`scrcpy`](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#wireless) to mirror the phone screen to computer, which uses `adb`.
I've followed the steps and it works:

```
# connect via USB
adb devices
adb tcpip 5555
# now unplug USB, and the following will work over WiFi
adb connect 192.168.1.14:5555
scrcpy
```

But when you reboot the phone or computer, doing `adb connect 192.168.1.14:5555` and `scrcpy` doesn't work anymore (NB: the phone IP hasn't changed, it's fixed).

Reading the answers from [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi), I see 3 options:

- plug the USB cable *each time* before doing a wireless connection, but this is annoying, and somehow reduces the interest of wireless...
- Use "ADB over network" (main answer's screenshot), but as noted by many people in comments: *"i do not have the "ADB over network" option in debugging option"*; so this option doesn't work for me
- other techniques that need root (not possible for me)

**Question: how to pair the phone and computer with a USB cable *only once*, and then be able to use `adb` between them *without* having to use a USB connection first, after each reboot?**

Note: I don't use Android Studio, but only `scrcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without root the phone. If your phone has rooted. You can use this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en. With this app you can easily debugs android apps with only wifi. Don't want USB cable even only first time.

Answer (score -1):

Based on all the information I have the next conclusion. Just for reference, how a low-level setup with changing `add` routes works inside, [described here](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/images/stories/pdf/lf_abs12_kobayashi.pdf). It comes up, there is a pretty straight thing inside changing navigation with `adb tcpip <port>`.

1. The first thing we need to do, it's setup system property with tcp port with name `setprop service.adb.tcp.port` (and values with a port number) By default, there is not such property.
2. And then just restart `adb` with few commands. `stop adbd` and `start adbd` on a device in order to debug bridge listen new port. What is the trick here, that you don't have access to this service and stop/start it without root. But it could be easily done, via Developer setting with stop/start debugging.

This few simple action hidden inside `adb tcpip <port>`. And the problem, that you cannot change system properties (point 1). That is why all application requires root access, it's just to change the single option. That is why, we need to connect with USB to debug bridge, which can change properties with his sepolicy.

So answering your question. I don't understand either, what is the problem or enabling this small setup in Developer options. But right now, it's possible to do so on some Roms, or devices with root access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't really understand it. What is your conclusion: is it possible or not without root?

Comment: @Basj It's not possible. You need to have root, or custom rom for that.