# Q: How to run flutter app on device without usb or connecting to computer

Tags: flutter

Is it possibly to run flutter app on device without connecting to computer, something like expo for Flutter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming that you're using an Android device, it should be possible if you pre-connect the device to the computer wirelessly after some initial setup provided here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Answer (score 6):

You can use [adb wifi](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983-android-wifi-adb) plugin. Or else you can use these commands(Which is mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893953/9485907)). You can write a *.bat file with these commands.

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555 // IP address of your device xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555
echo finished - unplug USB connection
pause
```

Note: This is only for Android devices

Answer (score 2):

### For Android:

1. Connect your Android device and adb host computer to a common Wi-Fi
   network accessible to both. Beware that not all access points are
   suitable; you might need to use an access point whose firewall is
   configured properly to support adb.
2. If you are connecting to a Wear OS device, turn off Bluetooth on the
   phone that's paired with the device.
3. Connect the device to the host computer with a USB cable.
4. Set the target device to listen for a TCP/IP connection on port 5555.

   adb tcpip 5555
5. Disconnect the USB cable from the target device.
6. Find the IP address of the Android device. For example, on a Nexus
   device, you can find the IP address at **Settings** > **About tablet** (or
   **About phone**) > **Status** > **IP address**. Or, on a Wear OS device, you can
   find the IP address at **Settings** > **Wi-Fi Settings** > **Advanced** > **IP
   address**.
7. Connect to the device by its IP address.

   adb connect device_ip_address
8. Confirm that your host computer is connected to the target device:

   $ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   device_ip_address:5555 device
   You're now good to go!

**If the adb connection is ever lost:**

1. Make sure that your host is still connected to the same Wi-Fi
   network your Android device is.
2. Reconnect by executing the adb connect step again.
3. Or if that doesn't work, reset your adb host:

   adb kill-server
   Then start over from the beginning.

[Source of information.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless)

### If you don't want to do all these steps manually then you can use this plugin in Android Studio:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7856-adb-wifi/

### See also:

https://android.jlelse.eu/connect-android-device-with-wifi-within-android-studio-3b1bc00c1e17

Comment: For iOS : https://medium.com/@mfqscode/how-to-debug-wirelessly-on-flutter-with-an-ios-device-5ea1ff55adf4

Answer (score 0):

For android device only, on a linux type OS.

> `adb tcpip 5555 && adb connect 192.168.***.***`

unplug your device and you're good to run.