# Is it possible to connect mobile with USB camera and Macbook/Windows at a same time to debug the Android Application?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, mobile-application, usb-camera

I want to create an Android application where I can process the Images from a USB Camera and run ML detections on them. I have Pixel 2XL, Logitech C920, and Macbook Pro, which I want to connect at the same time, so I can debug the application whenever it crashes/does not run. Right now, I am using ALogic type C dock, but it is not detecting the Mobile device for USB Debugging. Is there any way where we can debug the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I'm doing exactly the same and I'm using [ADB over Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi) for keeping my one and only USB-C available for wired UVC devices

short howto:

1. attach your device with USB-C cable, make sure it's one and only device (no emulators also)
2. optionally: check with `adb devices` is it visible
3. run `adb tcpip 5555`
4. disconnect device and check it's IP in some WiFi settings
5. run `adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555`
6. optionally: ensure with `adb devices` is it visible

now you can see your device in Android Studio as long as laptop/PC and Android device are connected to the same Wi-Fi

good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Upvoted. Just a suggestion, update the device_ip to show it as a place holder, I was thinking of it as it is to write.
E.g. <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>

Comment: may be just like in linked answer, approved. good luck!