# BlueScreen after Run emulator android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10, blue-screen-of-death

When im run android studio, or run emulator for android studio with manually or with cmd, always get bluescreen.
it say "your pc ran into problem and needs to restart. we're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you"
Stop code: IRQL Not Less or Equal
how can i fix it ?
im trying download another emulator and following tutorial on youtube, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factor,

I happened to get this issue because of my old PC with Lesser RAM size(4GB) and to rectify it, I connected my Android phone to PC for debugging/running apps from Android Studio.

You need to enable USB Debugging in your phone for that purpose.

NOTE:
You can view this blog post I made, which addresses the same issue.
https://whysurfswim.com/2015/07/11/sick-of-your-avd-theres-a-alternate-for-it/

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same problem. When I tried to install my app in emulator(Ram 8gb), my emulator crashes but kept running in background. As a result, I was unable to shut down my pc and have to disconnect power for shutting down.
use your phone for debugging your app. you can connect your phone using wifi. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens beacause of outdated drivers, try updating your drivers to latest version, and update the windows 10 to latest version. Also try by deleteing your current emulator device and create new device by enabling software renderer. For lower end pcs like yours I would recommend to use real device instead of emulators ans use ssds for better performances.