# How to Debug my Android Application Over WiFi Without a USB Connection?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wifi

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android version 10, and my USB connector does not work anymore. The Android docs state that I have to connect my phone to the host computer with a USB cable first before debugging via WiFi...

Are there any ways to work around this? I read one StackOverflow post that provided a solution (not sure if it works) for phones that are rooted, but I was hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Comment: @ADM Well, it wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but yes, that does answer my question lol. According to that post it seems that there is no way to debug on my phone without first connecting via USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your device is Android 10 you cannot init a Wireless connection without connecting it via USB first.

I don't know if the S10 is rooteable if you can root your device or it is already rooted you can follow the steps listed here:

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

You only need to prompt a few commands in your device to enable usb debugging via TCP.

Or you just need to wait for the Samsung S10 Android 11 update. Planned for this month.