# Android : how to bind computer network to smartphone network for development on physical device

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, usb-debugging

I would like to bind my computer's network to my smartphone's (physical) network when I debug on the latter.

This is done automatically on virtual devices but not when debugging on a physical device.

I can access services (api | via ip 10.0.2.2) on my local machine but I can't get onto the internet.

I've found adb commands but they don't work.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you have in mind with binding a network to another? Never heard of such.

Comment: And with an emulator you have access to internet too. What is going on?

Comment: The 10.0.2.2 IP provided by the emulator is a special network connection that only works because the emulator is part of your PC. If you want to establish a network connection from a physical device there is no such simple solution available. One simple way would the use TCP port forwarding via adb (e.g. through an USB connection). Then on the phone you could use 127.0.0.1 plus the forwarded port as target.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If computer and smartphone in one network via router you can use wireless connection with `adb`.

Go to smartphone settings, find dev options, enable usb debug. Then find wireless debug option (android 11+). Use `adb pair *ip:port*` with ip and port from screen, then `adb connect *ip:port*` in Android Studio terminal. For older android like 8 version possible also but more complicated (for example [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938/5894542)).